# Click Handler has suddenly stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that is both published and been working for months that has suddenly stopped being able to find click handlers (no change to the code).

IE. I get an error like this:

Error encountered: Script function not found: interfaceClass.myClickHandler

"interfaceClass.myClickHandler" does, in fact, exist and it is registered

```
var indF = app.createCheckBox("Create individual files")
        .setName('create')
        .setId('createBox');
    var chandler = app.createServerHandler('interfaceClass.myClickHandler');
    indF.addClickHandler(chandler);
```

It also doesn't seem to be anything specific to this handler.  ALL click handlers are failing.

Given this was working, I'm almost positive this is a result of Google doing an update that broke our code (which they've done in the past).  But I need to know what they changed so I can work around it.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently what they broke is that app.createServerHandler can no longer find functions defined like so:

```
var obj = {};

obj.method = function (e){

};
```

You *must* now use functions declared the following way:

```
function method(e){
}
```